# .htaccess не работает

Tags: apache, .htaccess, ubuntu

`.htaccess` напрочь игнорируется апачем. Почитал гугл, прописал `AllowOverride All` в `/etc/apache2/sites-available-default` - получил 500 ошибку. Почитал гугл, прописал

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

и, в общем, ничего. Та же 500 ошибка, гугл больше ничего не знает.

Comment: После изменений перезапускали? **sudo service apache2 restart**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё, разобрался. Нужно utf8 без BOM для файла .htaccess.